# Highlight Ticks in a more economic way

Tags: plotting, ticks

My question is about the `Ticks` function in the `Plot` framework.
If I want to plot a function and highlight a certain behavior, e.g. a maximum in a sine-wave, at a given x-value $x_0$, which I want to call "Max", then i have to add Ticks to my options in the following manner

```
Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,2*Pi},Ticks->{{{0.5*Pi,"Max"}},Automatic}]
```

[image: Sine-wave with highlight]

This way, I lose all the ticks $(1,2,3,4,5,6)$ that are there if I leave the option blank.

```
Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,2*Pi}]
```

[image: Sine-wave with blank options (automatic ticks)]

Is there an economic way to recover the ticks, which are there by default with a simple command? I have the feeling that entering all the ticks manually is a lot of useless work, when mathematica in principle knows how to add ticks automatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use  `` Charting`FindTicks `` or `` Charting`ScaledTicks `` to get the regular ticks and append additional ticks:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 Ticks -> {Append[Charting`FindTicks[{0, 1}, {0, 1}][##], {0.5 Pi,"Max"}]&, Automatic}]
```

[image]